# PMTA : handle bounce mail with acct-file

Tags: php, email, email-bounces, pmta

I use PowerMTA to send emails, and I don't understand sthg :

I would like to know simply if an email has been successfully received or has been bounced.

I've read that PMTA can handle this with acct-file.

Here is what I tried :

```
<acct-file /bounce.csv>
   record b,d
   record-fields b bounceCat,header_Message-Id
   record-fields d bounceCat,header_Message-Id
</acct-file>
```

Then I send a single email to 5 different people (those email address exist).

**Result expected in bounce.csv :**

For each *message_id* : a line with a "d" (delivered) record.
A total of 5 lines.

**What I get instead :**

For each *message_id*, I get several records like this :

```
d,success,<message_id_1@domain.com>
d,success,<message_id_1@domain.com>
d,success,<message_id_1@domain.com>
b,bad-mailbox,<message_id_1@domain.com>

d,success,<message_id_2@domain.com>
d,success,<message_id_2@domain.com>
d,success,<message_id_2@domain.com>
b,bad-mailbox,<message_id_2@domain.com>
```

Why many "d" record appear for each email sent? And why a "b" (bounced) record appear also ?

And which type of record should I use : a "b" record, a "rb" (remote bounce), or a remote status record? I'm a bit lost...

Any idea?